# vb.net implement strategy pattern with different interface

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

is it possible to implement strategy pattern with different parameters in VB.net?
For example I have the following code:

```
Public Interface InterfaceDataManipulation
Sub updateMyData()
End Interface
```

How to implemente updateMyData in the class that implements above interface class with different parameter, for example in class x :

```
Public Class X
Implements InterfaceDataManipulation
Public Sub updateMyData(ByVal x as String)
 Console.Writeline(x)
End Sub
End Class
```

But the IDE raises an error "class x must implement updateMyData on interface InterfaceDataManipulation"

Answer (score 2):

By adding a parameter you're not implementing the interface - The idea of the interface is that people can use your class by only knowing about the interface -so your sub with parameter wouldn't match their expectations.

There are probably many ways of skinning this cat, but these are a few of the options:

- Don't use the interface
- Implement your version of updateMyData as an overload, but you should still implement the original without the parameter aswell
- Pass in x as a property to your class, that the updateMyData method can then use, while still having a signature that matches the interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Class X
Implements InterfaceDataManipulation
Public Sub updateMyData(ByVal x as String) Implements InterfaceDataManipulation.updateMyData
 Console.Writeline(x)
End Sub
End Class
```

The method signature needs to be appended with the method it is implementing in the interface as show above.

Comment: Interesting, because when I combine the question's interface declaration and your class, I get "error BC30149: Class 'X' must implement 'Sub updateMyData()' for interface 'InterfaceDataManipulation'." and " error BC30401: 'updateMyData' cannot implement 'updateMyData' because there is no matching sub on interface 'InterfaceDataManipulation'." much as I would expect.